# Bin Packing(Searched quad groups for answers)

Tags: java, bin-packing

I am writing a bin packing program in one dimension. I want only one possible bin. So it does not include a lot of bin its only one. This program is only searching quad groups and explode if quad groups are not equal to the searching number. I want to search every possible group that is bigger than quads.
In example we have 60 60 50 40 45 35 25 15 and we are looking for summing equal to 180 and answer is 60 60 45 15 that's fine but if we search 250 it will not working.
Can you help me?
That's the link for program https://github.com/omerbguclu/BinPacking1D
That's the code for the algorithm o array is the numbers, a array is the location of answers

```
    public BinPacking() {

}

public void binpack(ArrayList<Integer> o, ArrayList<Integer> a, int wanted) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (wanted > 0) {
        control(o, a, wanted);
        if (is) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < o.size(); i++) {
            sum += o.get(i);
            summing(o, a, wanted - sum, i + 1);
            if (is) {
                a.add(i);
                return;
            }
            for (int j = i; j < o.size(); j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    sum += o.get(j);
                    summing(o, a, wanted - sum, j + 1);
                    if (is) {
                        a.add(i);
                        a.add(j);
                        return;
                    }
                    sum -= o.get(j);
                }
            }
            sum -= o.get(i);
            // "/////////////*******************////////////////////");
        }
        if (wanted != sum) {
            System.out.println("There is not an answer with quad summing method");
        }
    }

}

public void summing(ArrayList<Integer> o, ArrayList<Integer> a, int wanted, int loop) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (loop < o.size() && wanted > 0) {
        for (int i = loop; i < o.size(); i++) {
            if (wanted == o.get(i)) {
                a.add(i);
                is = true;
                return;
            }
            for (int j = loop; j < o.size(); j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    sum = o.get(i) + o.get(j);
                    if (wanted != sum) {
                        sum = 0;
                    } else {
                        a.add(i);
                        a.add(j);
                        is = true;
                        return;
                    }

                }
                // System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There is not an answer with binary summing method");
    }
}

public void control(ArrayList<Integer> o, ArrayList<Integer> a, int wanted) {
    for (int i = 0; i < o.size(); i++) {
        if (o.get(i) == wanted) {
            a.add(i);
            is = true;
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty well established and efficient mechanism for getting every possible combination of a set of objects. Essentially you treat membership of the combination as a `BitSet` which represents whether each member of the set is in the combination. Then visiting every combination is just visiting every `BitSet` combination.

Here's how I tend to implement it:

```
public class Combo<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

    private final List<T> set;

    public Combo(List<T> set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        BitSet combo = new BitSet(set.size());
        return new Iterator<List<T>>() {
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return combo.cardinality() < set.size();
            }

            public List<T> next() {
                int i = 0;
                while (combo.get(i))
                    combo.clear(i++);
                combo.set(i);
                return combo.stream().mapToObj(set::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So your solution would become:

```
for (List<Integer> combo: new Combo<>(...)) {
    if (combo.size >= 4 && combo.stream.reduce(0, Integer::sum) == total)
        ....
}
```

A hackier version of the same idea would be:

```
for (long l = 0; l < 1 << (input.size() - 1); l++) {
    List<Integer> combo = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{l}).stream()
            .mapToObj(input::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (combo.stream().mapToInt(n -> n).sum() == total) {
        System.out.println(combo);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this is a very futuristic solution for me :D I will search this classes I never used them before